# Detect access by api to password protected area

Tags: php, pdf-generation, user-agent, referrer

I'm using a simple service called [I'm PDF](http://www.impdf.com/index.htm) to create PDF versions on online invoices.  Right now, the client has to login to see the online version, but as a result, the api service doesn't have access to it either.  How would I detect that the pdf service is accessing the site and allow it accordingly without a password?

I thought $_Server['http_referrer'] would do it, but I didn't have any luck.  I wasn't sure even what the variables would be, so I had a var_dump($_Server)it emailed to me, whenever the page was visited.  It sent it beautifully when I went to the page, but when the pdf was generated, no luck.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to identify the user. The only way with this service seems to be to append something to the pdf URL (GET parameter).

So create some secret on the server side, sign user id with it, append it to impdf URL and parse it with your secret on request. You will end up with user id that you can use for authorization.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that the data appended should probably be either a one time password, or otherwise only lives as long as the user's current session is.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried looking at the IP address?

The service probably accesses the site from the same IP address (or range of addresses).  If that's the case, then all you have to do is check the remote IP address of the request, which I believe is in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` for PHP.

I should also mention that IP address [ACLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) are not quite perfect, though, because IP addresses can be [spoofed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing).  They probably should not be too heavily relied upon for security unless there is absolute control over (or guarantee of safety) of packets leaving and entering the network.  That said, they are most likely sufficient for your "simple" security requirements.

The [HTTP referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) is pretty much [trivial to circumvent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spoofing).  As such, it is not reliable enough for security and should be taken with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go for any of the above mentioned advices. Basically they all bring down your security measures.

I'd use an API such as PDFmyURL's API, which allows you to login directly via a host of standard ways. This makes sure you don't have to build anything new.

Direct link to section on accessing secure area: [PDFmyURL API documentation](http://pdfmyurl.com/html-to-pdf-api#secure)

Disclosure: I work for Kaiomi, which owns this service.